# javascript hash and ciphers implementation, any scripts that can take care of all of them?

Tags: javascript, hash, encryption

I'm looking to implement the following in js:

Hash: md5, sha1, sha128, sha256

Ciphers: aes128, aes192, aes256, blowfish, rc4

I know that there are many independent sources of code for each of those. But if possible I would like a complete suite of code that that efficiently shares functions and what not. It doesn't have to include everything in my list, I don't expect that, but anything is better than me getting individual scripts and piecing them together.

Comment: Google gives me: http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Comment: Just a note, in case you want to do this in a browser: [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [SJCL](https://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/) (Stanford Javascript Cryptography Library). A lot of these are now built into [WebCrypto API](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/).

Remember: [Javascript in the browser is perilous and dangerous](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/).

If you're looking for something safer, [sodium-plus](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium-plus) wraps libsodium and makes it easy to use.